# Unix case insensitive command line search containing wldcards and spaces

Tags: unix

I am attempting to come up with a method to remotely find a list of files on our AIX UNIX machine that meet, what seems in windows, like simple criteria. It needs to be case insensitive (sigh), use wildcards (*) and possibly contain spaces in the path.

For my tests below I was using the ksh shell. However it will need to work in an ssh shell as well.

I am attempting to implement secure FTP in Visual Basic 6 (I know) using plink, command line and a batch file.

Basically find a file like the one below but with case insensitivity:

```
ls -1 -d -p "/test/rick/01012017fosterYYY - Copy.txt" | grep -v '.*/$'
```

Thanks for any help.

```
ls -1 -d -p /test/rick/01012017[Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy] - [Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt] | grep -v '.*\/$'**
```

fails with:

ls: 0653-341 The file /test/rick/01012017[Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy] do
es not exist.
ls: 0653-341 The file - does not exist.
ls: 0653-341 The file [Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt] does not exist.

```
ls -1 -d -p /test/rick/01012017[Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt] | grep -v '.*\/$'**
```

success - as long as there are no spaces.

```
ls -1 -d -p "/test/rick/01012017[Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt]" | grep -v '.*\/$'**
```

fails with:

ls: 0653-341 The file /test/rick/01012017[Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy].[T
t][Xx][Tt] does not exist.

***-- Assumption: We cannot use quotes with wildcard characters***

```
ls -1 -d -p "/test/rick/01012017fosterYYY - Copy.txt" | grep -v '.*\/$'**
```

success. not case insensitive.

```
ls -1 -d -p /test/rick/[0][1][0][1][2][0][1][7][Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy] - [Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt] | grep -v '.*\/$'**
```

fails with:

ls: 0653-341 The file /test/rick/[0][1][0][1][2][0][1][7][Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr
][Yy][Yy][Yy][ does not exist.
ls: 0653-341 The file ][-][ does not exist.
ls: 0653-341 The file ][Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt] does not exist.

```
ls -1 -d -p /test/rick/[0][1][0][1][2][0][1][7][Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy][ ][-][ ][Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt] | grep -v '.*\/$'**
```

fails with:

ls: 0653-341 The file /test/rick/[0][1][0][1][2][0][1][7][Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr
][Yy][Yy][Yy][ does not exist.
ls: 0653-341 The file ][-][ does not exist.
ls: 0653-341 The file ][Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt] does not exist.

```
ls -1 -d -p /test/rick/01012017[Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy]?-?[Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt] | grep -v '.*\/$'**
```

success. not very helpful though.

```
ls -1 -d -p /test/rick/01012017[Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy][ ]-[ ][Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt] | grep -v '.*\/$'**
```

fails with:

ls: 0653-341 The file /test/rick/01012017[Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy][ d
oes not exist.
ls: 0653-341 The file ]-[ does not exist.
ls: 0653-341 The file ][Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt] does not exist.

```
ls -1 -d -p /test/rick/01012017[Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy]{ }-{ }[Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt] | grep -v '.*\/$'**
```

fails with:

ls: 0653-341 The file /test/rick/01012017[Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy]{ d
oes not exist.
ls: 0653-341 The file }-{ does not exist.
ls: 0653-341 The file }[Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt] does not exist.

```
ls -1 -d -p /test/rick/*01012017[Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy] - [Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt]* | grep -v '.*\/$'**
```

fails with

ls: 0653-341 The file /test/rick/*01012017[Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy] d
oes not exist.
ls: 0653-341 The file - does not exist.
ls: 0653-341 The file [Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt]* does not exist.

```
ls -1 -d -p "/test/rick/01012017[Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy] - [Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt]" | grep -v '.*\/$'**
```

fails with:

ls: 0653-341 The file /test/rick/01012017[Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy] -
[Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt] does not exist.

Comment: Please help us to help you: What files do you have, and what output do you wish to get?

Comment: I think it would be the right time to install GNU!`find`, e.g.: `ssh user@aixhost "/usr/local/bin/find /remotepath -maxdepth 1 -iname '*mask*'"`

Comment: I can't make it much clearer what I want. I have supplied many examples of my attempts to find a file with spaces in the name using case insensitive wildcards.

Comment: Thanks for the reference to find. It lead me to look at the '\' character that removes the special meaning of the following character. I put it in front of the spaces and got a return.

ls -1 -d -p /test/rick/01012017[Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy]\ -\ [Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt] | grep -v '.*\/$'

Comment: @Belmiris what you could make clearer is your intent at a slightly higher level. `grep -v .*/$` -- do you mean "I want to find files in a particular directory, not directories"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For case insensitive wildcard searches when -maxdepth and -iname flags are not available for AIX Find , you can pass the Find results to Grep:

```
find /test/rick/. \( ! -name . -prune \) -type f -print | grep -i ".*foster.*\.txt"
```

*find [InThisFolder] [ExcludeSubfolders] [FileTypes] | grep [InsensitiveWildcardName]*

Though, this can still be problematic if you have a folder structure like "/test/rick/rick/".

The following code gives results with the current directory signifier ".":

```
find /test/rick/. \( ! -name . -prune \) -type f -print | grep -i ".*foster.*\.txt"
```

But you can pass the results to sed and find "/./" and replace with "/".

```
find /test/rick/. \( ! -name . -prune \) -type f -print | grep -i ".*foster.*\.txt" | sed 's/\/\.\//\//g'
```

*** UPDATE ***

Based on this page:  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

I’ve come up with the following command (for loop on file expansion or globbing) which avoids the problematic  "/test/rick/rick/" folder structure from the find | grep solution above.  It searches a folder from any folder, handles spaces, and handles case insensitivity without having to specify escape characters or upper/lower matching ([Aa]).

Just modify the searchfolder and searchpattern:

```
searchfolder="/test/rick"; searchpattern="*foster*.txt"; for file in "$searchfolder"/*.*; do [[ -e "$file" ]] || continue; if [[ "$(basename "$file" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')" = $searchpattern ]]; then echo "$file"; fi; done
```

It does this:

- Set the folder path to search (`searchfolder="/test/rick";`)
- Set the search pattern (`searchpattern="*foster*.txt"`)
- Loop for every file on the search folder (`for file in "$searchfolder"/*.*;`)
- Make sure the file exists ( `[[ -e "$file" ]] || continue;`)
- Transform any base file name uppercase characters to lowercase (`basename "$file" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'`)
- Test if the lowered base file name matches the search pattern and if so
  then print the full path and filename (`if [[ $(basename "$file" | tr
     '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') = $searchpattern ]]; then echo "$file"; fi;`)

Tested on AIX (Version 6.1.0.0) in ksh (Version M-11/16/88f) and ksh93 (Version M-12/28/93e).

Answer (score 2):

`ls` doesn't do pattern matching, any wildcard expansion (*globbing*) is done by the shell. The glob pattern language is different from regular expressions. Read the ksh documentation for information about globbing ("File Name Generation" in the manpage).

So when you do:

```
$ touch foo flo fum
$ ls -1 f[ol]o
flo
foo
```

... *the shell* notices the globbing characters `[]`, reads the directory contents, replaces it with the matching files, and passes those as parameters to `ls`. You can show this by using `echo` instead:

```
$ echo f[ol]o
flo foo
```

---

`ksh` has globbing options available with the `~()` construct, option `i` is "Treat the match as case insensitive" :

```
ksh$ touch foo FoO FOO
ksh$ echo ~(i)foo
foo FoO FOO
```

---

`bash` has a `nocaseglob` `shopt` option:

```
bash$ shopt -s nocaseglob
bash$ touch fOo
bash$ echo FO*
foo
```

Although note that some globbing character needs to be present to make the magic happen:

```
bash$ echo FOO
FOO
bash$ echo [F]OO
foo
```

(to keep this option change local, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310957/how-to-undo-a-set-x/310963)

---

It looks as if you're using `grep -v '.*/$'` to remove lines that are directories. The `.*` is superfluous here -- `grep -v '/$'` is equivalent.

But `find` is a better tool for this kind of searching and filtering, implementing `-type f` (match regular files) by actually looking at the file attributes, rather than by parsing a bit of ASCII in a listing.

```
$ touch foo FOO FoO
$ mkdir fOo
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "foo"
./FOO
./foo
./FoO
```

Comment: I got this error: find: 0652-017 -maxdepth is not a valid option.

Comment: That will be a difference between AIX `find` and GNU `find`. GNU find might be installed somewhere. Otherwise `man find` and see what's there. I think `-prune` might do it, but I don't have an AIX system to try on.

Comment: @slim man on AIX Find:   -prune
      Always evaluates to the value True. Stops the descent of the current path name if
      it is a directory. If the -depth flag is specified, the -prune flag is ignored.

Comment: @slim what version of ksh do you have?  when I try `echo ~(i)foo` I get: `ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error: `(' is not expected.`  I have ksh Version M-11/16/88f.

Comment: @ktti `$ echo ${.sh.version}` returns `Version AJM 93u+ 2012-08-01`

Comment: @ktti That "88" means you've got a Korn shell from 29 years ago! Mine is a sprightly 5 years old. But I think all versions of ksh-93 have `~(i)`

Comment: @slim lol, yup on the 88.  FYI, `.sh.version` isn't set in ksh Version M-11/16/88f and `~(i)` doesn't work in ksh93  Version M-12/28/93e.  I get `ksh93: syntax error: '(' unexpected.`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `find`'s `-iname` option to allow for case-insensitive searching, so for the example you've provided any of the following should find your file:

```
find /test/rick -maxdepth 1 -iname '01012017fosterYYY - copy.txt'
# or
find /test/rick -maxdepth 1 -iname '01012017fosteryyy - copy.txt'
# or 
find /test/rick -maxdepth 1 -iname '01012017FOSTERyyy - cOpY.txt'
```

- `-maxdepth 1` : don't search in sub-directories
- `-iname` : allow for case-insensitive searching

Comment: I got this error:
find: 0652-017 -maxdepth is not a valid option.

Comment: you'll need to update your question with your shell (bash, ksh, sh) and version; keep in mind that for your remote call we'll need the shell and version of the remote machine

Comment: Sorry but none of the commands I google seem to work for getting the version of my shell. This OS seems very user hostile. I went with simply using my case insensitive wildcards and putting single quotes around the spaces. This is childishly simple in Windows.

Comment: (It was known since the beginning that the platform is `AIX`, it doesn't have GNU-find, unless someone install it. As I have suggested.)

Answer (score 0):

What I finally used (because I don't have access to -maxdepth or -iname) was just to use case insensitive wildcards together with quotes around spaces.

```
ls -1 -d -p /test/rick/01012017[Ff][Oo][Ss][Tt][Ee][Rr][Yy][Yy][Yy]' '-' '[Cc][Oo][Pp][Yy].[Tt][Xx][Tt] | grep -v '.*\/$'
```

That way I don't have to install or upgrade anything and probably cause more problems just so I can get a simple list of files.

NOTE: AIX UNIX will still throw in some garbage errors if you have any sub directories under the path. I tapped out on this and just parsed these useless messages out on the client side.

Thanks everyone who responded.